# Amazon ItemLookup API - Parameter Operation is missing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

While I am trying to send this request :

```
http://webservices.amazon.com/onca/xml?
          Service=AWSECommerceService&
          AWSAccessKeyId=[**HIDDEN**]&
          AssociateTag=[**HIDDEN**]&  
          Operation=ItemLookup&
          ItemId=B00008OE6I&
          Timestamp=[2016-01-09T18:55:23Z]&
          Signature=[**HIDDEN**]
```

I always get this error :

```
Error 400 : Bad Request

Parameter Operation is missing
```

What can i do ?

Comment: I see you haven't updated your question yet. Did you have any success in the meantime?

Comment: Yes i do , thank you sir. the problem was the white spaces like you say'd :)

Comment: You are welcome. I think it would be good if you accept the answer, because it might be helpful to someone else, it's a good practice. :)

Comment: I have the same problem, but URL is working in browser but when I send a request by curl then getting same bad request error, please help me

Answer (score 3):

The request is fine, you probably have some unnecessary characters or whitespaces between the URL parameters, which makes your request invalid. Paste your request into the browser address bar and look for "**%20**" or something unexpected/invalid between the **Operation** parameter and the parameter separator, **&**. It seems that Amazon doesn't recognize or is not able to extract the **Operation** parameter from your URL.

Also, you could update your question and paste the exact request (copied from the address bar) you are making.